# NameError: name 'message' is not defined - принять сообщение от пользователя

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot, telegram, python-telegram-bot

всем привет , есть инлайновые кнопки, по нажатию на которую должно отправляться сообщение пользователю что бы он ввел число а после в ответ на это число последовала отправка другого сообщения с инлайн кнопкой

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def keyboard_inline_call(call):
    elif call.data == 'button':
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,text='Enter num')
        try:
            if int(call.message.text) < 2:
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='❌')
            elif int(call.message.text) > 80:
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='❌')
            else:
                k = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                k.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Buy', callback_data='buy'))
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                text='что то', reply_markup=k)
        except ValueError:
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Sorry: Error')
```

но выходит ошибка
NameError: name 'message' is not defined

я понимаю что может быть проблема в колбек квери но я не знаю какой атрибут использовать в место message.text который используется в content_type (message)

UPD: исправил всё, но теперь бот отправляет сразу

```
Enter num
Sorry: Error
```

не давая ввести число

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если вы посмотрите, какой параметр был передан функции `keyboard_inline_call` - сможете найти ошибку, и понять почему `message` не был найден?) Потому что и нет такой переменной в локальной области видимости этой функции.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def keyboard_inline_call(call):
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,text='Send')
    try:
        if int(call.message.text) < 2:                             # ++
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='❌')
        elif int(call.message.text) > 80:                          # ++
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='❌')
    except ValueError:
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Вы ввели не число или ошибка')
```

Comment: это вроде бы и помогает но теперь вылазит такое
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Comment: @Hugason, это означает, что пользователь ввел текст, а не число, а как вы знаете - символы нельзя перевести в целочисленное значение `int`. Как вариант - напишите блок `try-except ValueError` и напишите что-то в духе `bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Вы ввели не число')`

Comment: через try - except не получается, целый день мучаюсь с этим, помоги пожалуйста, как нужно сделать?

Comment: @Hugason, подправил результат - только проверьте, или правильно сделал отступы, а то здесь не очень наглядно

Comment: изменил тему, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @Hugason, так сходу ответить сложно, так как мало информации в коде - это уже тема для отдельного вопроса. Вероятно, вы вызываете `callback` - `button`, но в самом `call.message.text` находится не число, поэтому и будет срабатывать `except ValueError`. Мне, кажется, что у вас неверно выстроена логика `callback`.Если нажать на кнопку  с`callback` = `button`, то как вы считаете введение значения пользователя? Это уже другой вопрос

Comment: да, нужно при нажатии button что бы выводилось сообщение о том что бы пользователь ввел число, он должен ввести число но не меньше 2 и не больше 80 как описано в этом отрывке кода, и если число от 2 до 80 то нужно вывести другое сообщение с другой инлайн кнопкой

Comment: @Hugason, для такого случая вам нужен `register_next_step_handler`. В интернете об этом много информации, но смогу предположить, что разбираться в этом вам придется где-то еще дня 2-3, так inline-кнопки совмещать с `register_next_step_handler`-ом не очень хорошая затея, и имеет свои недостатки. Я даже когда-то сам задавал подобный вопрос здесь, но толковых результатов на тот момент так и не получил. Попробуйте задать новый вопрос - может уже есть какие-либо продвижения в `telebot` Пока что единственным выходом вижу - как-то по-другому спроектировать и переписать код

Comment: Хорошо понял, но спасибо вам большое

Comment: написал решение для своего вопроса в отдельной теме 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1279695/433322