# Как ответить на сообщения пользователя в боте телеграм с кнопками

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, python-telegram-bot

нужно при нажатии button что бы выводилось сообщение о том что бы пользователь ввел число, он должен ввести число но не меньше 2 и не больше 80 как описано в этом отрывке кода, и если число от 2 до 80 то нужно вывести другое сообщение с другой инлайн кнопкой

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def keyboard_inline_call(call):
    elif call.data == 'button':
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,text='Enter num')
        try:
            if int(call.message.text) < 2:
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='❌')
            elif int(call.message.text) > 80:
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='❌')
            else:
                k = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
                k.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Buy', callback_data='buy'))
                bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                text='что то', reply_markup=k)
        except ValueError:
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Sorry: Error')
```

но бот отправляет сразу

```
Enter num
Sorry: Error
```

не давая пользователю ввести число

помогите как решить данный вопрос

Comment: Если бы это был aiogram я бы показал код, но тут другое. Однако изучите тему FSM. Это вам очень поможет

Comment: ниже написал решения, нашёл как сделать это,
использовал `bot.register_next_step_handler`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

получилось найти решение для моего вопроса

```
elif call.data == 'button':
            amount_item = bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,text='Enter num')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(amount_item, answer_item)
def answer_item(message):
    try:
        item_summ = message.text
        if int(item_summ) < 2:
            amount_item = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='❌')
        elif int(item_summ) > 80:
            amount_item = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='❌')
        else:
            ppk = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            ppk.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Buy', callback_data='buy'))
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
            text='<b>CHTO-TOTAM</b>'+ str(item_summ),
            reply_markup=ppk, parse_mode="Html")
    except ValueError:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Sorry: Error')
```